# not able to run c/cpp execs in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, g++, eclipse-cdt

I installed eclipse and then cdt on an ubuntu system recently and was trying to make the first runnable c/c++ proj..
I installed g++ also, and then created the first executable cpp 'Hello World' project
some files are created... then some issues...

1. even though Build Automatically is selected, I have to goto the
   project n do a Build Project to build it manually, and this i have
   to do every time I make a change
2. After Building manually, there are some new folders created with Binaries and Debug files and I can see `g++` commands in the console being executed. The project binary is output both to  debug n binaries folder. But i am not able to run these through the Green Play Button or any other way in eclipse. Even Run configuration is not showing any option for C/C++ project..
   Though I can goto terminal and run the binary myself through ./
   But I want to be able to run n debug this through eclipse.
   please help in fixing me this problem as I really love eclipse n have some c/cpp assignments coming soon..

Console info on doing a manual project build -

Build of configuration Debug for project qwe **

make all 
Building file: ../src/qwe.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/qwe.d" -MT"src/qwe.d" -o "src/qwe.o" "../src/qwe.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/qwe.cpp

Building target: qwe
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "qwe"  ./src/qwe.o
Finished building target: qwe

Build Finished **

Comment: plz help somebody...
am using ubuntu 12.04 n eclipse indigo thru apt-get install eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical problem and solved it by installing two additional "C/C++ Development Tools" that didn't show up when I originally filtered for "cdt" in Eclipse software update.  Filter for C++ instead and you'll spot them, after install and reboot everything works.